# How can I cause a state to be refreshed with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

- I am on the state:

  home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests.test
- I delete a test and retrieved a new list of tests without the test I deleted in response.data.tests.
- So now I want to go to this state:

  ```
   this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests', {
              examId: this.exs.exam.examId,
              subjectId: this.sus.subject.id,
              tests: response.data.tests
          });
  ```

But the router is thinking I already got all the resolves for the state so it does not try to repopulate the new list of tests.

Can someone tell me if it's possible to go to a state like this but have the resolves work.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify whether ui-router is not going from the .tests.test to .tests state, or if it transitions states, but just has stale data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional param that you can pass to `go`:

```
 this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests', {
        examId: this.exs.exam.examId,
        subjectId: this.sus.subject.id,
        tests: response.data.tests
    }, {
        reload: true 
    });
```

See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state for more details